# UPDATEIT SPOJ problem using Segment tree

Tags: python, time-limit-exceeded, bitwise

[UPDATEIT on SPOJ](https://www.spoj.com/problems/UPDATEIT/):

> ###### UPDATEIT - Update the array !
>
> [#bitmasks](https://www.spoj.com/problems/tag/bitmasks)
> You have an array containing n elements initially all 0. You need to do a number of update operations on it. In each update you specify l, r and val which are the starting index, ending index and value to be added. After each update, you add the 'val' to all elements from index l to r. After 'u' updates are over, there will be q queries each containing an index for which you have to print the element at that index.
>
> ###### Input:
>
> First line consists of t, the number of test cases. (1 <= t <= 10)
>
> Each test case consists of "n u", number of elements in the array and the number of update operations, in the first line (1 <= n <= 10000 and 1 <= u <= 100000)
>
> Then follow u lines each of the format "l r val" (0 <= l,r < n, 0 <= val <=10000)
>
> Next line contains q, the number of queries. (1 <= q <= 10000)
>
> Next q lines contain an index (0 <= index < n)
>
> ###### Output
>
> For each test case, output the answers to the corresponding queries in separate lines.
>
> ###### Example
>
> > **Input:**
> > 1
> > 5 3
> > 0 1 7
> > 2 4 6
> > 1 3 2
> > 3
> > 0
> > 3
> > 4
> >
> > **Output:**
> > 7
> > 8
> > 6

**Code:**

```
from sys import stdout,stdin

arrSum = [0] * 10001
def update(i,n,val):
    while(i <= n):
        arrSum[i]+=val
        i+=(i&(-i))

def query(i):
    sum = 0
    while(i >0):
        sum+=arrSum[i]
        i-= (i & (-i))
    return sum

def range_update(i,j,n,val):
    update(i,n,val)
    update(j+1,n,-val)

t = int(stdin.readline())
for _ in range(t):
    n,u = stdin.readline().split()
    n = int(n)
    u = int(u)
    for _ in range(u):
        l,r,val = stdin.readline().split()
        l = int(l)
        r = int(r)
        val = int(val)
        range_update(l+1,r+1,n,val)

    k = int(stdin.readline())
    for _ in range(k):
        index = int(stdin.readline())
        print(query(index+1))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review@SE. One advice I give and try to follow: code the way you think about a problem. One observation about problems on platforms like SPOJ: the time limits are carefully crafted such that suboptimal approaches fail, at least for the biggest test case. (Re-)Try "dry execution" of the example, but with n and every index multiplied by 42.

Comment: Is there anything in particular you want reviews to shed a light on?

Comment: How does the implementation presented motivate `using Segment tree` in the title?

Comment: I have used 2 power n approach using bit mask